# How do I decelerate the ripening of bananas?

Tags: food

I buy a bunch of bananas, but they usually go too ripe before I can finish all of them. **Is there a way to make them ripen less quickly?**

Comment: Keep them cool. out of a paper bag, and away from bruising.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a number of things you can do to slow the ripening of bananas:

- Keep them cool - bananas will ripen less quickly in the fridge
- Wrap the stems in cling film - this is where most of the ripening gas ethylene comes from. Covering it will reduce the amount of gas that escapes
- Separate the bananas from other fruits - Other fruits will produce even more ethylene, so keep bananas well away
- Don't bruise them - bruising will break down the skin membrane, causing the release of - you guessed it - more ethylene. Consider a banana hook.

Comment: It's worth noting that bananas kept in the fridge will look worse than they actually are. The "shell" will often begin to change in colour as if the banana has gone bad, but the inside will be perfectly fine.